# error : InvalidArgumentError: StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: [4 [Op:StringToNumber]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

can someone  help me to fix this error please :
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

```
InvalidArgumentError: StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: [4 [Op:StringToNumber]
```

I know that I should convert the string array to float array but I don't now how?

first I create a dataset from a txt file that i had create

```
    data = np.genfromtxt('C:\image echantillon\DATATR',delimiter =',', dtype=str)
    X=data[:,0:3]
    #X_train = np.asarray(X)
    tf.strings.to_number(X, out_type=tf.float32)
    Y=data[:,3:]
    tf.strings.to_number(Y, out_type=tf.float32)
```

I tried to convert that data by using  tf.strings.to_number(x, out_type=tf.float32)

After that I create a sequential model

`````
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=3, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    ````
my file look like this 
``

    ['[4' ' 3' ' 5'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
    ['[4' ' 3' ' 5'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
    ['[4' ' 3' ' 5'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
    ['[4' ' 3' ' 4'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
    ['[4' ' 3' ' 4'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
    ['[4' ' 3' ' 3'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
    ['[4' ' 3' ' 3'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']``
`````

Answer (score 0):

You should change the position of your quotes.

Change all lines in your file from

```
['[4' ' 3' ' 5'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']
```

to:

```
[[' 4' ' 3' ' 5'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0']]
```

Comment: How can I do that please ?

Comment: I need more information about the file or the file itself to be able to answer that in detail. The most time-consuming way would be to do it by hand. If it is a text file, csv or something similar, then you can automate it with Python.

Comment: OK, I create my file with this code ````    
#image.save('image.bmp')
IM=np.array(image)

im = cv2.imread('image.bmp')
img=Image.open('Image.bmp')
#######################
#########creation file datatr#################
#class mer

M = img.crop((0,50,20,70))
M.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
for j in range(20):
    for i in range(20):
        [r,v,b] = M.getpixel((i,j))
        f=open('C:\image echantillon\DATATR', 'a')
        f.write(str([r,v,b,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])+"\n" )
        f.close()

Comment: When you write your file this way`f.write(str([r,v,b,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])+"\n" )` it cannot look like this `['[4' ' 3' ' 5'] [' 1' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0' ' 0]']`. And in `data = np.genfromtxt('C:\image echantillon\DATATR',delimiter =',', dtype=str)` you set the comma as delimiter. But you don't write a comma in the file. I'm sorry, but i need your whole code or at least the original file `C:\image echantillon\DATATR` otherwise i can't help you.

Comment: I Can't post all the code because it's so long(the comments can not allow that) but the code above is the important part which create the file``img=Image.open('Image.bmp')
#######################
#########creation fichier datatr#################
#classe mer

M = img.crop((0,50,20,70))
M.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
for j in range(20):
    for i in range(20):
        [r,v,b] = M.getpixel((i,j))
        f=open('C:\image echantillon\DATATR', 'a')
        f.write(str([r,v,b,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])+"\n" )
        f.close()``